# Split a column on a comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle query that returns result like

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
  1        -A,D    -DEF
  2        -B,C    -JHI
```

How can i get the result like

```
Column1 Column2  Column3  Column4
  1       -A       -D      -DEF
```

Comment: Is that `-A,B` or just `A,B`?

Comment: techdo has a good question is the - associative?

Answer (score 3):

Utilize the `SUBSTRING` function to receive part of the String and the `INSTR` function to find the position of the comma.

```
select
    column1,
    substring(column2,1,instr(column2,',')-1) as column2a,
    substring(column2,instr(column2,',')+1) as column2b,
    column3
from mytable
```

Example:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ada12/12

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
select
  Column1, 
  substr(Column2 , 1, instr(Column2, ',')-1) as Column2, 
  substr(Column2 , instr(Column2, ',')+1) as Column3, 
  Column3 as Column4 
from(
      select  1 as Column1, '-A,D' as Column2, '-DEF' as Column3 from dual
)x
```